# Add multiple files from multiple directories to unique .tar.gz archives using Python

Tags: python, tar

I have directories of files that I need to add to a tar archive. The directory structure is:

```
..\root\path\dirname\somefiles.txt
```

and the .tar.gz files containing somefiles.ext should be deposited into ..\root\path\ as:

```
..\root\path\dirname.tar.gz
```

The code that I currently have is:

```
import os, tarfile

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for dir in dirs:
        tar = tarfile.open(dir + '.tar.gz', 'w:gz')
        for file in files:
            tar.add(os.path.join(root, file))
        tar.close()
```

However, this pulls files from `..\root\path\` rather than `..\root\path\dirname\`. How can I write this to pull the files out of each directory and add them to the archive of the same name of the directory?

**EDIT**

With the use of @mVChr's code, I was able to obtain what I needed. I added `arcname=f` to remove the directory within the archive; I have no idea why I did not implement this before:

```
import os, tarfile

for root, dirs, _ in os.walk('.'):
    for d in dirs:
        with tarfile.open(d + '.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
            for _, _, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, d)):
                for f in files:
                    tar.add(os.path.join(root, d, f), arcname=f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things...

You can, but you probably shouldn't use `dir` and `file` as variable names since those already have meanings in Python.

You should probably put your `tarfile.open` in a `with` statement so that you can be sure that it will `close()` no matter whether the execution ends normally or by an error.

That being said, this slightly altered code accomplishes your task:

```
import os, tarfile

for root, dirs, _ in os.walk('.'):
    for d in dirs:
        with tarfile.open(d + '.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
            for _, _, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, d)):
                for f in files:
                    tar.add(os.path.join(root, d, f))
```

Comment: I see your point referring to the variable names. This also creates a directory within the archive: ..\root\path\dirname.tar.gz\dirname\somefiles.ext Also you have left out tar.close().

Comment: I didn't leave out `tar.close()`, that was my point about using `with`, it does it for you. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement and `inspect.getsource(tarfile.TarFile.__exit__)`

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake. Is it possible to truncate the directory hierarchy in the process? I just want the files, no folders...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import os
import glob
import tarfile

def main():
    directories = [ dirname for dirname in glob.glob('*') if not dirname.endswith('.tar.gz') ]

    for directory in directories:
        print('working on {}'.format(directory))
        for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            tar = tarfile.open('{}.tar.gz'.format(directory), 'w:gz')
            for filename in filenames:
                tar.add(os.path.join(root, filename))
            tar.close()

main()
```

Comment: This creates a directory in the archive as ..\root\path\dirname.tar.gz\dirname\somefiles.ext I am looking for ..\root\path\dirname.tar.gz\somefiles.ext